# Запись двух значений в одну ячейку для всех строк. Python, Excel, Win32com

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

Я новичок в python и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
У меня есть таблица Exсel, в два столбца которых приходят значения(напр:1,235448), мне нужно чтоб python объединил две ячейки и записал в третью и так для всей таблицы. У меня получилось объединить их вручную, но не могу сделать для всех строк. Сделал цикл но он пишет их подряд (не объединяет). Пробую через команду AutoFit() но получаю ошибку.
Буду рад любому варианту решения

```
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')  
    wb = excel.ActiveWorkbook
    sheet = wb.ActiveSheet
    val1 = sheet.Range("Q1").Value
    val2 = sheet.Range("R1").Value
    sheet.Range("S1").Value = "%.1f" % (val1) + ' - ' + "%.1f" % (val2)
    val3 = sheet.Range("Q2").Value
    val4 = sheet.Range("R2").Value
    sheet.Range("S2").Value = "%.1f" % (val3) + ' - ' + "%.1f" % (val4)
    sheet.Range("S1:S2").AutoFit(sheet.Range("S1:S45"), win32.constants.xlFillDefault)
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Excel/Exel.py", line 100, in proba_vr
sheet.Range("S1:S2").AutoFit(sheet.Range("S1:S45"), win32.constants.xlFillDefault)

TypeError: AutoFit() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Comment: можете выложить небольшой пример входного и результирующего Excel файлов на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: @MaxU https://dropmefiles.com/dbaRk

Comment: можете также выложить то, что вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: @MaxU https://dropmefiles.com/2nAHz

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None)

mask = df.iloc[:, [6,7]].all(axis=1)

df.insert(4, 'E', '')

df.loc[mask, 'E'] = df.iloc[:, 6].round(1).astype(str) + ' - ' + df.iloc[:, 7].round(1).astype(str)

df.to_excel(r'c:\temp\result.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
```

Результат:

```
In [85]: df
Out[85]:
             0       1    2              3          E         4         5         6         7         8     9    10     11   12   13   14     15     16
0   09.02.2019  Москва  ФИО  НЧ:0000000001  0.3 - 0.3  0.350309  0.345991  0.303694  0.862500  0.787500  5.05  7.75  12.80  1.0  0.0  0.5  0.400  12.10
1   09.02.2020   Минск  ФИО  НЧ:0000000002  0.2 - 0.6  0.167391  0.225356  0.606651  1.000000  1.900000  3.40  8.15  11.55  0.8  0.2  0.6  0.500   8.15
2   09.02.2021  Казань  ФИО  НЧ:0000000003  0.3 - 0.4  0.286529  0.269189  0.444167  1.504167  0.554167  3.50  8.90  12.40  0.6  0.4  0.5  0.400    NaN
3   09.02.2022    Нара  ФИО  НЧ:0000000004  0.2 - 0.2  0.577130  0.245443  0.177127  1.887500  0.862500  3.60  8.25  11.85  0.4  0.6  0.5  0.400    NaN
4   09.02.2023   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000005  0.3 - 0.5  0.127991  0.328307  0.543679  0.512500  1.187500  3.25  3.85   7.10  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.500    NaN
5   09.02.2024   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000006  0.4 - 0.3  0.318624  0.359375  0.321998  1.350000  0.425000  3.55  3.80   7.35  0.6  0.4  0.7  0.400    NaN
6   09.02.2025   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000007  0.3 - 0.4  0.241344  0.308857  0.449770  0.750000  1.250000  5.80  2.70   8.50  0.4  0.6  0.5  0.400    NaN
7   09.02.2026   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000008  0.3 - 0.1  0.585132  0.281535  0.133248  1.375000  0.112500   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.0  1.0  0.7  1.000    NaN
8   09.02.2027   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000009  0.2 - 0.3  0.476320  0.192910  0.326226  2.104167  2.129167  5.35  2.40   7.75  0.8  0.2  0.6  0.500  13.00
9   09.02.2028   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000010  0.2 - 0.5  0.268471  0.216242  0.514065  0.937500  1.087500   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.500   7.55
10  09.02.2029   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000011  0.2 - 0.2  0.652479  0.188216  0.156885  2.200000  0.875000  5.00  9.25  14.25  1.0  0.0  0.7  0.500    NaN
11  09.02.2030   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000012  0.3 - 0.3  0.401979  0.257146  0.340698  1.225000  1.091667  3.45  4.45   7.90  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.375    NaN
12  09.02.2031   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000013  0.3 - 0.5  0.195191  0.298807  0.505953  0.937500  2.087500   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN  0.7    NaN    NaN
13  09.02.2032   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000014  0.1 - 0.8  0.044686  0.082119  0.840770  0.487500  2.754167   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN  0.5    NaN  14.10
14  09.02.2033   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000015  0.2 - 0.3  0.462856  0.219866  0.316201  1.325000  0.975000  5.45  3.25   8.70  1.0  0.0  0.5  0.500  12.80
15  09.02.2034   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000016             0.918259  0.076791  0.000000       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN  0.5    NaN    NaN
16  09.02.2035   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000017  0.1 - 0.1  0.693040  0.094761  0.104973  3.687500  2.287500  5.55  4.50  10.05  1.0  0.0  0.6  0.500   9.45
17  09.02.2036   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000018  0.2 - 0.2  0.654534  0.187808  0.155234  2.545833  0.579167   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.500   3.40
18  09.02.2037   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000019  0.6 - 0.2  0.207342  0.616640  0.176019  0.737500  0.587500   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.0  1.0  0.8  0.500  10.00
19  09.02.2038   Город  ФИО  НЧ:0000000020  0.2 - 0.2  0.631118  0.198093  0.169016  2.254762  0.980952   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.0  1.0  0.8  1.000  10.60
```

Comment: Да это работает, если я запускаю отдельным файлом. Но в моей программе это не очень помогает, наверно из-за того сама программа на win32com и работает с открытыми книгами и кучей активных листов то в DF записывается всякая фигня, хотя книга и лист указывается конкретно, он все равно пытается записать значения которых нет даже в этой книги, это надо все перелопачивать чтоб найти что конкретно он в df пишет. Попробую как то обойти это. Спасибо Вам за помощь